# ¿Cómo aplicar el principio de inversion de dependencias en el provider?

Tags: poo, flutter, dart

Quiero que mi proyecto siga los principios SOLID, y para eso quiero saber si el acoplamiento que siempre se ve entre la UI y los provider en diversos tutoriales es algo que viole el principio de inversión de dependencias o no.

Recuerdo la definición del princpio:

> A. Las clases de alto nivel no deberían depender de las clases de bajo
> nivel. Ambas deberían depender de las abstracciones.
>
> B. Las abstracciones no deberían depender de los detalles. Los detalles
> deberían depender de las abstracciones.

Con esto me refiero a esta aplicación que se ve mucho en tutoriales:

```
class MiProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  //...
}

class ClaseDeUI extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     MiProvider miProvider = Provider.of<MiProvider>(context);
     //...
  }
}
```

Como se ve, la clase de UI instancia directamente la clase del provider y no una interfaz, generando acoplamiento entre estas dos clases.

Entiendo que la "clase de alto nivel" sería el provider y la "clase de bajo nivel" sería la de UI. Y que "los detalles" en este caso sería la clase de UI.

¿Sería mejor utilizar abstracciones y pasar el provider por el constructor?

*Aclaración: No estoy preguntando por opiniones personales (ya que sino la pregunta sería cerrada), estoy preguntando acerca de aplicación de los principios SOLID a Flutter.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contestada en SO en inglés [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74774005/how-to-apply-the-principle-of-dependency-inversion-in-the-provider/74774241?noredirect=1#comment131966955_74774241). Traduzco simplemente:

Como dice el principio,

> las entidades deben depender de abstracciones

por lo que la implementación que comento arriba es errónea. Esta sería la correcta:

La abstracción:

```
class MyProvider implements ChangeNotifier {
 void method();
}
```

Sus implementaciones:

```
class MyNetworkProvider extends ChangeNotifier implements MyProvider {
  @override
  void method() {...}
}

class MyDatabaseProvider extends ChangeNotifier implements MyProvider {
  @override
  void method() {...}
}
```

Esta vendría siendo la "inyección de dependencias", donde se elige que implementación se utilizará:

```
runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
  create: (_) => MyNetworkProvider(),
  child: ...
));
```

Y así se utilizaría en la clase UI:

```
class UIClass extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     MyProvider myProvider = Provider.of<MyProvider>(context);
     //...
  }
}
```

De esta forma la clase UI no conoce acerca de la implementación real. Solo conoce la abstracción reduciendo el acoplamiento.

Comment: Normalmente, los providers se usan para una pantalla en concreto, por lo que no tiene mucho sentido hacer uso de inversión de dependencia en este caso. Sería más bien los repositories o los services que use dicho provider, quienes deberían usar dicho principio. Pero bueno, para gustos colores. En estos temas, cada uno tiene una opinión.